# Trim sheet name in Sheet interface (Apache POI)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to get Sheet by using:

`Sheet sheet=workbook.getSheet("sheetName");`

But in my workbook, some sheet names has whitespaces. How to make "trim search"? Is is possible to do something like this:

`Sheet sheet=workbook.trimSheetSearch("sheetName");`

Or

`Sheet sheet=workbook.indexOfSheetSearch("sheetName");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to iterate each `Sheet` to improve your search with [`Workbook.getNumberOfSheets()`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getNumberOfSheets--) and [`Workbook.getSheetAt(int index)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getSheetName-int-).

Something like :

```
for(int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++){
    String s = workbook.getSheetName(i);
    if(checkName(s, nameToFind)) return workbook.getSheetAt(i);
}
return null; // sheet not found
```

For the search method, you can do a dirty solution like

```
public boolean checkName(String n1, String n2){
    return n1.replaceAll(" ", "").equalsIgnoreCase(n2.replaceAll(" ", ""));
}
```

I let you improve that method (I will not do everything here ;) ). Note that this might not compile because I don't have an actual system to run this but this should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks bro! You saved me! :) Unfortunately i can't upvote your comment (i'm new in StackOverflow and don't know everything here yet)